# Reading cookies from a different website for ads? How is it possible?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, ads

I suspect this is not a suitable question for stackoverflow and I hope I am not crossing the lines. I know that cookies from a certain website can not be read from a different website. But all the time, I see ads on my facebook page or other pages that are related to my amazon browsing or while I was shopping in a different website. How is this possible?

Comment: It's the NSA feeding facebook with the data from all the hidden cameras in your house.

Answer (score 3):

The cookies itself cannot be read by other websites. The data can however be shared in a number of other ways. Foremost networks like Facebook / Amazon agreeing to share (read sell) the data they have collected about you.

e.g. http://news.discovery.com/tech/gear-and-gadgets/how-facebook-sells-your-personal-information-130124.htm

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is, they use other techniques to share your daya - they don't (and should not be able to) read cookies of other domains.

Answer (score 0):

It's server-side (or middle-man side, for the NSA). Google analytics has to go thru a google server. Google is probably logging that. Since people are probably logged in anyway, it makes it pretty easy to give you targeted ads. I'm pretty sure that there is no way to get another site's cookies.